# How can c++ host pass byte[] array "output parameter" to a c# method on both windows and linux?

Tags: c#, c++, coreclr

I know which tag I should use when the c++ host passes an input parameter to a c# method on both windows and Linux, but in my project, the c# api has a "byte [] array" output parameter like the following, I didn't find any tag for this case.

C# code:

```
public static string DoWork(int msgSize, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] byte[] errMessage)
```

C++ code:

```
typedef char* (*doWork_ptr)(int dataSize, char * data);
```

I tried the **[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)]** as above, but it can only be used as "input" rather than "output". Then which tag should I use for the output parameter on both windows and Linux? Thanks.

FYI:

1.You can refer https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/hosting/HostWithCoreClrHost for the basic code, I just replace the "DoWork" function in the project.

2.The following article mentions how to export a c-style array in c# but it doesn't mention the case for the output parameter.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays

3.The host is written with c++ which calls the method in a c# dll with coreclr on both Linux and windows.

Comment: How about using a plain (unsafe) IntPtr? You can use `GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned)` to pin a managed byte array for unmanaged access.